# What's the idiomatic way to get a "string writestream"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Perhaps I'm thinking about this in a view too shadowed by the JVM, but…

I'm using a third-party API which has a function declaration that takes a WriteStream (I believe it only uses the `.write()` method).

I'd like to be able to use the result of this directly, not in a file stream or something (as is normally done) but into a string.

In Java, there are classes like `ByteArrayOutputStream` for this purpose. What's the best way to do it in Node?

---

Right now, I'm just doing this

```
var strbuf = [];

func({write: function(str) {strbuf.push(str);}});

var str = strbuf.join('');
```

But that is obviously verbose, ugly, and not entirely clear as to its purpose.

Comment: Does the API not support emitting any events? Generally something like this would emit a data event. What is the API?

Comment: No. It's a synchronous library.

Comment: Not sure then. What's the library?

Answer (score 0):

WriteableBufferStream in [buffertools](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-buffertools) does the same thing slightly more generically.